# Launch chat program script from an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a script given to us from a third party launch by clicking an image on our website.

The company that provided the code have not been very helpful. I am hoping someone could help me out.

Here is the chat program code:

```
<!-- Embedded ClickAndChat.com: Insert the script below at the point on your page where you want the Click To Chat link to appear -->

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://server2gateway.clickandchat.com/include.js?domain=www.palmbeachschools.org_ace_studentzone"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
if(typeof sWOTrackPage=='function')sWOTrackPage();
</script>

<!-- End of embedded ClickAndChat.com -->
```

and here is the Html for the image/button

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="http://www.palmbeachschools.org/ace/images/SZ-Counselor-Main.png" width="390" height="130" alt="" onclick="()" />
</a>
```

Comment: When I click on my image the program does not launch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a page that will load the lodash lib when you click on the google image.  You should be able to just change the script url and the image src to what you want.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        console.log("lodash not loaded " + typeof _)

    });

   function loadScript() {
       if (typeof someObject == 'undefined') {
           $.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js', function(){
               //Stuff to do after someScript has loaded
                console.log("lodash loaded : " + _.VERSION);
           });
       }
   }

    </script>

   <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" onClick="loadScript();"></img>
</body>
</html>
```